# spark application completes with SUCCESS status when an exception is thrown

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark application on yarn, which my goal is do some ETL from jdbc to elasticsearch.
However, when I check the log ,there is some errors like,this error is due to network problem :

```
17/12/01 00:35:19 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1317.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1381, worker50.hadoop, executor 1): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Connection error (check network and/or proxy settings)- all nodes failed; tried [[192.168.200.154:8201, 192.168.200.156:9200, 192.168.200.155:8201]] 
at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This means that connection failed and lost some data in this process.The job finalStatus should be failed, but spark returned me with `{"state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED"}`
WHY? My spark version is 2.2.0

Comment: Review the logs and see if the task `1317.0` has not been re-tried as `1317.1` and hence Spark has managed to recover from the failure.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski no,not been re-tried